# Can't ping a host on local WiFi network with Apple's Mac as WiFi Hotspot

Tags: macos, networking, wireless-networking, android, ping

I've set up a local network in my home using Mac as a WiFi hotspot. I've connected a Ubuntu laptop and an Android device to this network. The set-up works fine, but when I try to ping my Android device from my Ubuntu laptop, the ICMP request times out most of the time. Sometimes, the ping is successful but most of the time, it's not.

Is there a restriction that a Mac can't proxy ICMP requests through it? When the destination (Android device) is not reachable, the ARP table in my Ubuntu laptop shows incomplete MAC address of Android device:

```
    evinish@68DK8R1:/$ arp
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
192.168.2.1              ether   ea:06:88:cd:47:64   C                     wlan0
192.168.2.4                      (incomplete)                              wlan0
```

Sometimes the host becomes reachable on it's own and the ARP table becomes:

```
    evinish@68DK8R1:/$ arp
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
192.168.2.1              ether   ea:06:88:cd:47:64   C                     wlan0
192.168.2.4              ether   d0:51:62:a2:7b:35   C                     wlan0
```

What could be the reason for that? Please help me!

Comment: What is your actual goal of pining your android device?  Just for the sake of pinging it?

Comment: I'm running a file server on my phone. Apparently, I can't get my network up and running!

Comment: You don't want a hotspot you want an ad hoc network - 2 different things.

Comment: Okay, let me sum up like this: LAN cable from my broadband service provider connects to my macbook. Now, I've created a wireless bridge in my laptop for Internet sharing to my Ubuntu laptop and Android device. If I run a local file server in my MAC, it can serve files to my newly created wireless bridged network. So, this is a ad-hoc network too where my MAC provides local IP addresses from it's own DHCP pool (192.168.xx.xx range). If I run the same server in Ubuntu, I can't access any files from my Android device because, for some reason, Ubuntu is unable to ping Android (no L3 connection)!

Comment: I am trying to get adb over network working and facing the same issue.

Comment: @takrishna: My problem is resolved. After the latest software update on Mac, everything is working fine now. Which Mac OS are you using?

Comment: Which version that would be ?

Comment: I'm using OS X El Capitan.